# How to find from where a database getting its information in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql workbench as my db client. I have two databases one is giving data `mydb_1` and another is receiving the data called `mydb_2`.

So, below are my doubts :

1. How can be the data transformation is happening between these DB's?I have checked whether any stored procedure call or triggers have been written but i was unable to find out that because stored_procedures are not visible to my credentials?
2. I suspect may be i don't have required privilege's, if i don't have proper privilege, so even i wouldn't see the stored procedures? is it dint?
3. Is there any alternative way to find, how mydb_2 is getting updated?

Comment: You may want to mention how your databases are connected? Have you set up replication?

Comment: Yes, i want to know what  SQL query or Stored Procedure  happens between these databases. If i found that i can easily identify from which tables of mydb_1 providing data to mydb_2 tables .

Comment: What I meant with my comment, is, that you haven't mentioned any details about your problem, so we can't answer it.

Comment: how to find out how the data transformation happening between these two databases? is there any way to find that?

Comment: You are just repeating your question again and again. If your english isn't good enough to understand my comment, I doubt it will be good enough to really understand an answer. Maybe you have better luck on site where your language is used.

Comment: No, its not like that. Actually, what sort of details are you required?

Comment: Like I said, we have no idea what you mean with one database is giving and the other is receiving data. How did you implement that? We can't tell you what is probably going wrong on the way when we don't know the way. Isn't that logical?

Comment: There are literally no details at all. Your procedures are not visible to your credentials. Whatever that should mean. But I understand at least, that you have two different users? You might want to add more details about that, too. Maybe your one user just hasn't the rights to see certain data? Oh, and you also haven't mentioned what's wrong with your data at all. Is something missing? Is it transformed? Add as much details as possible.

Comment: Ok, let me explain precisely. As i said, my 2nd database inherit particular information and customize as its own table from 1st database. So i want know, what are all the possible ways to share the information between two databases.? Like how to extract the data from other db?

Comment: As you said, i guess it might be the privilege issue for my credentials.

Comment: Now I don't even know, if you're just looking for a way to backup your database. Whatever...I'm giving up here. Good luck. Maybe this page is of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/help Learn how to ask questions....

Comment: No,Thanks. Just keep it with you.

Comment: I will learn how to ask question in stack but my kind advice is, just learn how to comment in humble manner. Good Bye. Thanks for spending your time on my incomprehensible question.

Comment: Well, I guess that's just a cultural thing. As a german I could easily argue, that you were rude by wasting my time, because you didn't come around with information although I more than once asked for it. So in my view I was polite enough. But indians, or asians in general tend to value politeness more than productivity. Always nice to see when a westerner asks "have you understood it?" and the asians like "yes, yes, of course. thank you", although they clearly haven't understood it but are too shy to aks for further clarification. Just a cultural thing. Anyway, like I said, good luck...

Comment: It's not shy. I'm in the place to not reveal all the information's. Ultimately this was an one to one conversation but you were brought into cultural and continental part. I'm sorry to say this, even if you reach heights but really not having politeness to discuss with people, that's barren. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, it was a bad example. My point is, that you considered it rude, that I posted this link and that I gave up on you. Thing is, I can't help you with this little information. And when I would have given this link to a german, he probably would have thought "okay, it seems that's something I can improve on" and that's it. Asians tend to consider this as rudeness, I don't. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just to acquaint, it doesn't mean german and indians will take it in different way. It depends on every individual but not by nationality. Even after if you thinking like this. It shows your ignorance and also actually it is a bad example. Glad to converse with you.

Comment: Of course there are people everywhere around the globe that are more sensitive than others. That's why I said "probably" and "tend" to not say, that everyone is like that, but the majority (like I said, it's just different cultures. And I haven't said that one is better than the other). And btw, you're throwing with words like ignorance around now, which is considered quite rude in my view. Just to let you know. Luckily I'm not that easily offended as you seem to be...typical asian ;-) just kidding...

Comment: No, that's why have mentioned even after but if it really hurts. I submit my kind apologies. Just to kidding- If we two are not really offended, Perhaps this conversation would have been over a few messages before.    
Anyways that's been a healthy converse with you. Thanks a lot for the link. From my side, will improve whatever you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the access restriction, I was unable to see the stored procedure code.
So, I enabled the MySQL binary log to find, how the data transformation is happening between two databases for the restricted user. Even though
this didn't give entire information but partially I have found some information which can sort my problem.